# Loop Through Entire AIX File System to Find a Keyword Occurrence

Tags: unix, scripting, aix

How do I go through entire file system to locate a keyword - that is traverse all directories.  My nested for loop is not going through complete file system.  What is wrong with my logic, please?

```
    for d in `find . ! -name . -prune -type d|xargs -n 1 basename`
    do
    if [ -d "$d" ]
    then
    for d in ./*/ ; do (cd "$d" &&  echo directory "$d" && find . -exec grep -n -i "KeyWord" {} /dev/null \;); done
    else
    echo "Processing file $d"
    fi
    done
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). This question rather belongs to http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: First issue is that you use the same variable "d" in both loops. The 2nd loop doesn't take into account what "d" is (file or dir or something else).

Comment: From your code I understand that you want to execute "grep keyword" on all files from under the current directory. You don't need a script for it, might be done with: `find . -type f -exec grep -n -i "keyword" {} /dev/null \;` . If you have some other reasons why a script should be used, then please describe them.

Comment: your explanation helped me understand that find is all I need to traverse the file system -

Comment: With GNI `grep` you have a recursive option `grep -r KeyWord /`.

Comment: Be aware that you don't write your findings to a file: grep will also look in that file and add the lines found to the same file over and over.

Comment: Start Midnight Commander then press `Esc` then press `?`

Answer (score 0):

From your code I understand that you want to execute "grep keyword" on all files from under the current directory. You don't need a script for it, might be done with: `find . -type f -exec grep -n -i "keyword" {} /dev/null \;` . …
                    – czvtools